# JButton customize , setBounds has no effect

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

My goal is to make something like this :

[image: image1]

but sadly this is my current state :

[image: image2]

prethanks to all.
this is my code :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    Square sq1;
    Square sq2;
    JPanel jp;

    public MainFrame(){
        super("New Game");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        sq1 = new Square();
        sq2 = new Square();
        jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        sq1.setBounds(250, 300, 400, 120);//just random numbers to see if change
        jp.setBounds(250, 300, 50, 120);

        add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jp.add(sq1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        jp.add(sq2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setSize(500,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Really, tinypic is not a site serious enough to get links from here.

Comment: Why are you using JButtons? Why not use JPanels or images?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to remove the default JButton format so it matches the frame's background. Is that correct?

Comment: yes dogwin you are correct. i actully didnt know i had this kind of option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the JButton's format, you can set it's properties like so:

```
sq1.setOpaque(false);
sq1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
sq1.setBorderPainted(false);
```